# How to handle an Exception while opening a new intent in Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have a notification messenger, I want user to have an access to Google Play Store when they press "push Notification", otherwise, redirect them to url.
So my code is this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://dev?id=" + appPackageName2)));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM Notification")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I want something like this on the above code:

```
try {
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://dev?id=" + appPackageName2)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=" + appPackageName2)));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PackageManager.resolveActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity(android.content.Intent,%20int)) to determine if there is an app installed that can handle a specific intent. You can use that to check if the `market:` URI can be handled.

Make sure you carefully read the associated javadoc since it has some notes on implicit/explicit intents.